# Using CoreData to save data for the flashcards

Tags: swift, database, oop, core-data

I'm trying to create an analog of Quizlet app by myself, however, I have run into the problem where my app doesn't run and the data doesn't seem to be saved. I have created a DataController to manage the data as well as CoreData with entities: name, term, definition and id and name "FlashCardData". I have got a TermDefinitionView where user can type the name, term, definition and create new "block" or in other words another flashcard. The problem is that I'm unable to save the data using the current method.

Here's the DataController() which basically controls the data:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class DataController: ObservableObject {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "CoreData")
    @Published var savedFlash: [FlashCardData] = []
    init() {
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Core Data failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
    
        }
       
    }
    func fetchRequest() {
            let request = NSFetchRequest<FlashCardData>(entityName: "FlashCardData")
            do {
                savedFlash = try container.viewContext.fetch(request)
            } catch let error {
                print("Error fetching... \(error)")
            }
        }
    
    func save(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        do {
            try context.save()
            print("Data saved")
        } catch {
            print("We could not save the data...")
        }
    }
    func add(name: String, term: String, definition: String, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let data = FlashCardData(context: context)
        data.id = UUID()
        data.definition = definition
        data.name = name
        data.term = term
        
        save(context: context)
    }
    
    func edit(data: FlashCardData ,name: String, term: String, defintion: String, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        data.name = name
        data.term = term
        data.definition = defintion
        
        save(context: context)
    }
}

/*func fetchRequest() {
    let request = NSFetchRequest<FlashCardData>(entityName: "FlashCardData")
    do {
       savedFlash = try container.viewContext.fetch(request)
    } catch let error {
        print("Error fetching... \(error)")
    }
    
}
 */
```

here's the TermDefinitionView, in it I tried to use DataController's Environment object but it doesn't seem to work out:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import CoreData

// ViewModel for managing flashcards

struct TermDefinitionView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = TermDefinitionViewModel()
    @Binding var showNew: Bool
    @State var term = ""
    @State var definition = ""
    @State var name = ""
    @Environment (\.managedObjectContext) var managedObject
    @Environment (\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @EnvironmentObject var dataController: DataController

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    List {
                        ForEach(viewModel.termdefpairs.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                            TermView(term: $viewModel.termdefpairs[index].term, definition: $viewModel.termdefpairs[index].definition, name: $viewModel.termdefpairs[index].name)
                        }
                        .onDelete { index in
                            self.viewModel.termdefpairs.remove(at: index.first!)
                        }
                        
                    }
                    /*.navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                    //    viewModel.save()
                    }) {
                        Button(action: {
                            showNew.toggle()
                            viewModel.save()
                            
                        }) {
                            Text("Save")
                        }
                    })*/
                    .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Save") {
                        dataController.add(name: name, term: term, definition: definition, context: managedObject)
                        dismiss()
                    })
                    Spacer()

                    Button(action: {
                        viewModel.addNew()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                            .resizable()
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.title2)
                            .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                    }
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .padding()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TermDefinitionView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TermDefinitionView(showNew: .constant(true))
    }
}

struct TermView: View {
    @Binding var term: String
    @Binding var definition: String
    @Binding var name: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                
                Text("Name")
                    .font(.headline)
                
                TextField("Enter name", text: $name)
                    .padding()
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
            }
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                
                Text("Term")
                    .font(.headline)
                
                TextField("Enter term", text: $term)
                    .padding()
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
            }
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                Text("Definition")
                    .font(.headline)
                
                TextField("Enter definition", text: $definition)
                    .padding()
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
            }
        }
        .padding()
        
    }
}

struct TermAndDefinition: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var term: String
    var definition: String
    var name: String
}
```

here's also a TermDefinitionViewModel with ability to add new "block" where the user can type in

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

final class TermDefinitionViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var termdefpairs: [TermAndDefinition] = [TermAndDefinition(term: "", definition: "", name: "")]
    
    private var dataController = DataController()

    func addNew() {
        termdefpairs.append(TermAndDefinition(term: "", definition: "", name: ""))
    }
    
    func save() {
        for pair in termdefpairs {
            dataController.add(name: pair.name, term: pair.term, definition: pair.definition)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When dealing with CoreData there is nothing more efficient that using the Apple provided property wrapper. You are not listening to the store, that is the main issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an uncommon problem here at stackoverflow when dealing with your own DataController/DataManager class. The class contains its own persistent container and store so everywhere in your code where you create an instance of it a new store will be created and you end up with data in your app being persisted in different stores and that are almost impossible to fetch correctly and will possibly also lead to crashes.

A good solution to this is to make the class into a singleton or shared.

First we add a `shared` property

```
class DataController: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = DataController()
    ...
```

Then you can leave it there and access the same instance of your DataController by using

```
DataController.shared
```

and make sure you remove any calls to `DataController()` in your code. Or we can take this one step further and make it a singleton by marking the init as private which means it will be impossible to call it from outside the class.

An example of how to use this new `shared` property:

```
func save() {
    for pair in termdefpairs {
        DataController.shared.add(name: pair.name, term: pair.term, definition: pair.definition)
    }
}
```